# Clear selected sites from history (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> show your recent browsing history.

While you can individually remove single items, but that is very labour-intesnive. You can also clear history by date, but that's not what I need because I'm trying to find a specific site I visited a few weeks ago and there is a lot of clutter.

Is there an easy easy to selectively remove *all* items from a specific site only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible:

- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to display the history
- Type the website name in the search field at the top to show only it
- Click the selection box of the first item in the list
- Scroll to the end of the list
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the selection box of the last item
  in the list to select all items
- Type <kbd>Del</kbd> and the deed is done.

Comment: Fantastic tip, thanks! Resorting to the "manual click down the line one-by-one" is beyond tedious.